# Ajust DateTime.Now for a server in another time zone

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Scenario**
I have an application hosted in the USA but it is used by a company in Asia. Obviously the time zone is different, and some parts of the system uses `DateTime.Now` to write logs and other stuff with the ocurrence date.

**Question**
Is there a way to ajust `DateTime.Now`?
*(say always get + 6hours different from server clock)*

How can I get the local DateTime (Asia), instead the datetime of the server (USA)?

***PS***: I don't have problems with multiple time zones. Is just one, the time zone of the Company headquarters.

Comment: Well **[this article](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/9/how_to_display_dates_and_times_in_clients_timezone)** explains to handle it with javascript and MVC. Hope you might be interested.. and even **[this with pure MVC](http://blog.platformular.com/2013/06/03/display-datetime-based-on-users-timezone-in-asp-net-mvc/)**

Comment: Your comment helped me more than the answers, If you care to put this in a answer I check it as correct.

Comment: Not a probs.. we are just here to help.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practices for handling datetime for global operations is always store all the data using `UTC` format and while displaying it shall be converted to the local datetime based on client timezone

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at DateTimeOffset https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx

It represents a point time relative to UTC. It is good way to store DateTime when it might be generated from differents time zones.

However, you are already using `DateTime.Now`, and you need a solution to your problem. You can convert the timezone like this (supposed you want to convert from asia [where the app is running] to eua):

```
var convertedDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
    yourDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Pacific Standard Time");
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx to to find the exactly timezone to solve your problem.